# New to React - How do I go about fixing/improving this component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state, jsx

I'm new to the React framework and recently wrote the below code but have been asked to understand what is wrong with it and how I could improve/fix this component.

Please could someone advise a better way of structuring this component and why this approach? Thanks!

```
class App extends React.Component {  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: this.props.name || 'Anonymous'
    }
  }    
  render() {
    return (
      <p>Hello {this.state.name}</p>
    );  
  }
}
```

Comment: This article might help explain whats going on here - https://medium.com/@justintulk/react-anti-patterns-props-in-initial-state-28687846cc2e

Answer (score 0):

Unless `name` is supposed to change at some point, your component does not need to be stateful. Simply use the `name` prop, and use `defaultProps` to provide the default value:

```js
class App extends React.Component {  
  render() {
    return (
      <p>Hello {this.props.name}</p>
    )
  }
}
App.defaultProps = {name: 'Anonymous'}
```

You actually don't need to use a class for such a simple component:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <p>Hello {this.props.name}</p>
  )
}
App.defaultProps = {name: 'Anonymous'}
```

See the [Function and Class Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) section for more information about functional vs classes component.

Answer (score 0):

The construction of the state cannot be done that way. You must use componentDidMount() and setState(),

```
componentDidMount() {
 this.setState({
   name: this.props.name
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you receive some content from an input, or you just want to display this state? If you just wanna display this state, you can just change constructor block with **state = { name: 'Anonimus'}** and call it in your jsx just as you did.